# Is there a way that I can put two or more words string with spaces in if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to input something like without the snake cases or underscore, like only "Nothing is true." and not "Nothing_is_true." but every time I do that it's not reading the if statement.

Is there any other way to do it?

I'm new to coding, sorry if you find my question so dumb

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer1;
    System.out.println("When men are blindly following the truth, remember...");
    answer1 = inp.next();
    if (answer1.equals("Nothing_is_true.")) {
        System.out.println("Correct.");
    } else System.out.println("Wrong.");
}
```

Comment: `next` only reads the next token, which is separated by spaces per default. To read a whole line, use `nextLine` instead

Comment: what is the correct answer you are looking for? question is little bit confusing. Is it "Nothing is true." should be correct or "Nothing_is_true." is correct. What your question says is you are about to find  "Nothing is true." but in your code you have found "Nothing_is_true."

Comment: sir @Dinithi , I'm just asking if instead inputting "Nothing_is_true.", can I input "Nothing is true." with spaces... in my code "Nothing_is_true." is what I've input because if I typed it with spaces, it's not working.

Comment: @Mumuchim got it. consider the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `inp.next()` will only input the string up to space (by default). To input "nothing is true" with `next()` you have to use a loop until it reaches `return`. But with `nextLine()` you can input a line so that it could contain spaces.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer1;
    System.out.println("When men are blindly following the truth, remember...");
    answer1 = inp.nextLine();
    if (answer1.equals("Nothing is true.")) {
        System.out.println("Correct.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for my case, you can try it out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maxim {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner (System.in);
        String [] answer1 = {"Nothing is True", "Nothing is true."};
        System.out.println("When men are blindly following the truth, remember...");
        String answer = inp.nextLine ();
        int assassins = 0;
        while (assassins < answer1.length) {
            if(answer1[assassins].equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                System.out.println("When men are limited by morality and law, remember...");
                String [] permitted = {"Everything is Permitted", "Everything is Permitted."};
                String answer2 = inp.nextLine ();
                if (permitted[assassins].equalsIgnoreCase(answer2)){
                    System.out.println("You are an Assassin."); 
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Answer."); 
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong Answer."); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).